# How do I debug the AllowAutoPlay procedure not being called in a WPF app

Tags: windows, com, autoplay, usb-drive

Reference: [How to prevent autoplay and run my own app when inserting an USB-Flash drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831114/how-to-prevent-autoplay-and-run-my-own-app-when-inserting-an-usb-flash-drive)

From a WPF app I need to suppress Autoplay for digital cameras I attach with a USB cable.

Thomas provided a good answer.  I took Thomas’ working code and used it in a VS 2013 project where I created a new WPF Application.  The sample App works great.  I took the exact same code and put it into my real WPF application and the AllowAutoPlay procedure is never called.  I did create a new Guid for the Autoplay class and registered it in the registry at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoplayHandlers\CancelAutoplay\CLSID  for my real app just like I did for the sample app.

What approach should I take to debug my WPF app? I dumped the Running Object Table to the Console, and it looks correct. I am much more familiar with the old Windows Forms Application structure where I would say some message is being missed or handled incorrectly.

I need some help how to debug this.

I tried dumping the Running Object Table and it looks correct.  I tried Thomas’ code in a new WPF application it ran as expected.